# Sending buffer through message queue

Tags: c, linux, pointers, ipc, message-queue

Hi I'm writing a program that sends a set of bytes through a message queue like so ...

```
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <stddef.h>

key_t key;
int msqid;
struct pirate_msgbuf pmb = {2, { "L'Olonais", 'S', 80, 10, 12035 } };

key = ftok("/home/beej/somefile", 'b');
msqid = msgget(key, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);

/* stick him on the queue */
msgsnd(msqid, &pmb, sizeof(struct pirate_msgbuf) - sizeof(long), 0);
```

The above example is a simple program from beejs website that resembles mine.

What I'm doing however is sending a message with a struct like so ...

```
struct msg_queue{

    long message_type;
    char * buffer;

}
```

Now before I send my msg_queue, I created some alternative buffer that contains all sorts of information including null characters and such. Now when I do something like this ...

```
struct msg_queue my_queue;
my_queue.message_type = 1;
my_queue.buffer = "My message";
msgsnd(mysqid, &pmb, sizeof(struct msg_queue) - sizeof(long), 0);
```

I have no problems receiving the pointer and reading the values stored at that string. However if I were to do something similar like ...

```
struct msg_queue my_queue;
my_queue.message_type = 1;
my_queue.buffer = sum_buffer_with_lots_of_weird_values; // of type char *
msgsnd(mysqid, &pmb, sizeof(struct msg_queue) - sizeof(long), 0);
```

The pointer I pass through my queue to my other process will read garbage and not the values stored. I tried making my arbitrary array as a static char *, but that doesn't help either. How do I properly pass in my buffer through the queue? Thanks.

Comment: Hey thanks, ya I know that processes have their own memory space that is not shared. I just thought that since pointers = arrays, at least in most cases that it doesn't seem consistent that msgsend() would only send the address pointed to for dynamically allocated memory space, where a const char * string would send the contents in the fixed length array instead. I suppose my only choice is to to use a fixed length array which depresses me. I thought that buffer = malloc(number_of_bytes); would be the same thing as buffer[number_of_bytes];.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't be sending a pointers to another process, they have no meaning (or point to something very different) in another process' address space.

Message queues aren't great for unbounded data like variable length strings.  Change your pointer to a fixed length char array sufficiently big to hold the largest string and copy your string into the array before writing the queue.  Or use another type of IPC such as domain socket.

Answer (score 2):

Message Queue is used for inter-process communication.
When you malloc some memory in one process, it only exist in that process memory space not accessible by other process.

when you send that pointer over, you are sending a address space which is not accessible. It may even result in segmentation fault.

One way is to limit your buffer size, if applicable.

struct msg_queue{

```
long message_type;
char buffer[MAX_LEN];
```

}

Another way is to send it 2 times. The first msgsnd, sends the size of buffer to expect.
The next send, you send the char array over, using the size of the first send. :)

On receiving end, you first get the size, then receive the buffer.

Other way is to use pipes or socket.

Answer (score 1):

"msgsend()" will only read the bytes in your buffer.

If one of those bytes happens to be a pointer (to some string or object somewhere else) ... guess what - the receiver will just get the binary pointer.  Not the data being pointed to.

What you need to do is pack the *entire* contents of your message into a buffer, then send that linear buffer.

Comment: So the only way to do this is to create a fixed array[]. I suppose I thought that a pointer to allocated memory was the same thing as a message buffer.